# Unexpected token 'export' when trying to use the Preact plugin in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, preact

I am currently trying to migrate a Next.js project from React --> Preact. 
I have added `next-plugin-preact` as a dependency and I changed my config also. 
Here is the `next.config.js`:

```js
// @ts-check
const configureBundleAnalyzer = require("@next/bundle-analyzer");
const withPreact = require("next-plugin-preact");

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  swcMinify: true,
  compress: true,
  images: {
    domains: ["firebasestorage.googleapis.com", "localhost", "lh3.googleusercontent.com", "source.unsplash.com"],
  },
  i18n: {
    locales: ["en"],
    defaultLocale: "en",
  },
};

const withBundleAnalyzer = configureBundleAnalyzer({ enabled: process.env.ANALYZE_BUNDLE === "true" });

module.exports = withBundleAnalyzer(withPreact(nextConfig));
```

And then I tried to run `pnpm run build` but it did nothing. Just killed the script right away. 
Then again I tried to run the dev server with `pnpm run dev` but it threw this error:

```
:\Default_Folders\Desktop\Projects\Javascript + Dart\AppName\web\node_modules\.pnpm\preact@10.11.3\node_modules\preact\compat\server.browser.js:1
export {
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
    at internalCompileFunction (node:internal/vm:74:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1141:20)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1182:27)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1081:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:922:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Default_Folders\Desktop\Projects\Javascript + Dart\AppName\web\node_modules\.pnpm\next@13.1.5_ive3jjn476xyi3ikfsqwmh5x74\node_modules\next\dist\server\render.js:7:45)    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:14)
```

I tried to look into the file in `preact/compat/server.browser.js` and this is what's present:

```js
export {
  renderToString as renderToStaticMarkup, renderToString
} from 'preact-render-to-string';
```

So I tried to temporarily just change the contents of the file to:

```js
const {
  renderToString: renderToStaticMarkup, renderToString
} = require('preact-render-to-string');

module.exports = { renderToStaticMarkup, renderToString }
```

and then it threw this error:

```
Error: Next.js requires react >= 18.2.0 to be installed.
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\Default_Folders\Desktop\Projects\Javascript + Dart\AppName\web\node_modules\.pnpm\next@13.1.5_ive3jjn476xyi3ikfsqwmh5x74\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack-config.js:1756:11)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1218:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1272:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1081:32)
```

Here is my `package.json` if needed:

```json
{
  "name": "app_name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "chrome 90",
    "edge 90",
    "firefox 90",
    "opera 90",
    "safari 14"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@next/font": "latest",
    "@react-icons/all-files": "^4.1.0",
    "firebase": "^9.14.0",
    "next": "^13.1.5",
    "next-plugin-preact": "^3.0.7",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "preact": "^10.11.3",
    "preact-render-to-string": "^5.2.6",
    "react": "npm:@preact/compat@^17.1.2",
    "react-dom": "npm:@preact/compat@^17.1.2",
    "react-hot-toast": "^2.4.0",
    "react-ssr-prepass": "npm:preact-ssr-prepass@^1.2.0",
    "sharp": "^0.31.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@next/bundle-analyzer": "^13.1.2",
    "@types/node": "^18.11.9",
    "@types/nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.25",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.46.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
    "eslint": "^8.28.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "^13.0.5",
    "postcss": "^8.4.19",
    "prettier": "^2.8.0",
    "prettier-plugin-tailwindcss": "^0.2.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.2.4",
    "typescript": "^4.9.3"
  }
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: @Andy That article is quite junk; the user copy/pasted the same instructions for v12 and called it a day. Next v13+ doesn't support Preact and probably won't, unless Vercel takes an interest in support. If one wants to use Preact and Next, they'll need to stick to v12.

Comment: Cheers for the heads-up @rschristian